# Remove tag script when JQUERY

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex

I have a system of posts, where the publisher can embed code another site to reference content. However, I am having a problem with the LookBook.nu site.

The site of this embedded code contains a script tag that calls `jQuery 1.6` and causes my system to crash.

I wanted to remove this script tag with regex. Is this possible?

This is the embedded code:

```js
<!--BEGIN HYPE WIDGET-->
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.2/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="http://lookbook.nu/look/widget/7625244.js?include=all&size=medium&style=button&align=center"></script><div id="hype_container_7625244">
</div>
<!--END HYPE WIDGET-->
```

Ps: impractical use noConflict is because I have to replace all the scripts of my system. It would take me too long to do this.

** Sorry, I don't speak Engish. Google Translate is my best friend. :D

Comment: When I see these kind of questions I always think of this answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/1732454#1732454

Comment: It's possible, but pointless. You can't remove it from the DOM with client side JS until it has been parsed. But the time it is parsed, the code has already executed.

Comment: Stick them in an iframe or ask them to not include it.

Comment: @charlietfl **impractical to use noConflict because...**

Comment: not hard to wrap all your code in an IIFE to be able to use noConflict with very little effort ... if that is last resort

Comment: @Grimbode - Classic!!  By far my favorite SO answer of all time!

Comment: @Quentin I will validate before execute the script

Comment: @LeonardoAlcântara — You can't do that because the script tag being added to the DOM will cause it to be executed.

Comment: @Quentin That would be if the script had been written in HTML. In my situation it is still in a string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The big question in this case is how the snippets get into your HTML source. If you load the code dynamically via AJAX and add it with .innerHTML() (or JQuery's .html() method for that matter), you can first filter it with a regex and replace the offending script tag. I'd try somthing like this:

```
\<script\s+src\=["'][^>]*?jquery[^>]*?\>\<\/script\>\n?
```

If you use this and replace it with an empty string BEFORE you inject the code into your DOM, than you should be fine.

If you already output the code serverside, e.g. in PHP you could also replace the tag with `preg_replace()` before echoing it.

**The important thing is only to do the clean up *before* inserting it into the DOM.**

P.S.: pattern updated to prevent it from matching another tag that goes before it.

Comment: It works, but if the first script. If another script tag before this removes both.

Comment: Indeed, but can be easily corrected. Use this pattern instead: `\<script\s+src\=["'][^>]*?jquery[^>]*?\>\<\/script\>\n?`